# AWS RDS database - Incompatible-network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm creating a database on AWS RDS, but every time I do, the status is Incompatible-network.

[image]

I'm wondering if it is because my Subnets have a deny all:
[image]

But I can't seem to delete the deny all, it is disabled:

[image]

A subnet attched to the db also doesn't seem to exist:

[image]

The VPC has an internet gateway:

[image]

Why does my database have an Incompatible-network?

**UPDATE**: subnet-7cbaf624 does not exist anywhere (subnets, network ACL, VPC, route table etc.) but is listed in my DB subnets. Not sure how to remove.

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-incompatible-network/. Quite a few options, "deny all" is just the default, and is overridden by the higher priority "allow all" rules you have.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have tried most of that. I don't understand how to see if I've reached my quota. All I can see is the quota on my account and the default quota but not if i have reached my quota.

Comment: @ceejayoz actually this subnet on the db subnet-7cbaf624 does not exist in my subnets. How do I delete it from the VPC/DB?

Comment: subnet-7cbaf624 is not on my VPC, network ACL or route table either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this. There was a non-existant subnet attached to my database. The only thing I can do is create a new VPC, I believe, as AWS seems to think my VPC has the missing subnet and attaches it to the DB upon creation if I choose that VPC during creation.